# ElasticSearch - Single match to multiple

Tags: elasticsearch

Note that I am a complete newbie with ElasticSearch and I'm on a time crunch. I've got the query below:

```
{
    "query": {
        "filtered": {
            "query": {
                "match": {
                    "state": "VA"
                }
            },
            "filter": {
                "and": [
                    {
                        "bool": {
                            "must": [
                                {
                                    "match": {
                                        "status": "Active"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "sort": [
        "dom"
    ],
    "size": 1
}
```

At the moment, the codebase only supports searching for items with one state in particular. I am trying to modify it to support a list of possible state values. Now, I've seen where one can use `should` and `terms` but the results for both are empty data sets.

I've tried looking this up but examples I've seen either don't work, or have very poorly explained (if at all) solutions, or depend on reading and absorbing pages of documentation (for which I simply do not have the time). How would I modify the top query to search for multiple values?

**Update**

Running the following:

```
curl -XGET localhost:9200/listings/_mapping/listing/field/state?pretty
```

I have acquired this mapping:

```
{
  "listings" : {
    "mappings" : {
      "listing" : {
        "state" : {
          "full_name" : "state",
          "mapping" : {
            "state" : {
              "type" : "string"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

**Update 2**

I've updated the mapping to set it to `not_analyzed` and enabled the `store` option. Data has been reimported. The new request looks like this:

```
{
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{
                "and":[
                    {
                        "bool":{
                            "should":[
                                {
                                    "terms":{
                                        "state":["VA","MD"]
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    },{
                        "bool":{
                            "must":[
                                {
                                    "match":{
                                        "status":"Active"
                                    }
                                }
                            ]
                        }
                    }
                ]
            }
        }
    },
    "sort":["dom"],
    "size":1
}
```

Comment: What's the mapping for the `state` field and provide a data sample of what gets in that field.

Comment: It's a string (two chars, uppercase), and apparently `analyzed`. I've tried executing a statement to change it to `not_analyzed`, but it complains that the index already exists.

Comment: Yes, if you want to change the mapping you need to recreate the index. And you still didn't provide the mapping :-) and a sample document.

Comment: Recreating the index involves dumping and reloading the data, right? That's going to be a hard sell because this data takes hours to load.

Comment: Ok. If your `state` field is `not_analyzed` and has in it `VA` or `MD` then it should work. Now the next question: how is `status` field? As I see you are searching for upper case `Active`. To be able to do this use `not_analyzed` for it or search for lowercase `active`.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try replacing the inner "query" for your "reverse engineered" query?

Something like this:

```
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "match": {
                "state": "VA"
              }
            },
            {
              "match": {
                "state": "MD"
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
        "and": [
          {
            "bool": {
              "must": [
                {
                  "match": {
                    "status": "Active"
                  }
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  "sort": [
    "dom"
  ],
  "size": 1
}
```

By the way, this query is a bit messy. You could reestrucuture it combining the "must" and "should" clauses under a single "bool". You could then discard the "filtered" query and use the single "bool" immediately under root "query" tag, or discard "query" section of "filtered" and use only the "filter" part.

Comment: I attempted this as well, and it did not return a result set.